# How do you change the variable in a function from a different class and call it back?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tkinter

I am making a game with levels and in each level, I will need to be using different operators and/or different ranges. My problem is that I don't know how to change the variables in a function from a different class. I would like to do this so I don't need to copy and paste my code making it lengthy. I'd like to use self.Answer and self.strQuestion for mulitple scope.

The code below is just to make the classes functional.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import random
from Tkinter import messagebox

class BattleMaths(tk.Tk):
     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):        
          tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
          container = tk.Frame(self)

          container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

          container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
          container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

          self.frames = {}

          for F in (StartPage, levelone, leveltwo):
               frame = F(container, self)
               self.frames[F] = frame
               frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

          self.show_frame(StartPage)

     def show_frame(self, cont):
          frame = self.frames[cont]
          frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

          lvl1_button = Button(self, text="LEVEL 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(levelone))
          lvl1_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
```

I want to put the questions def into class leveltwo while changing it to `self.Answer = int(numOne) * int(numTwo)` and  `self.strQuestion = "{} x {}".format(str(numOne), str(numTwo))`

```
class levelone(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

    def widgets(self):
          #widgets here

    def question(self): 

          self.UserAnswer = ''
          numOne = random.randrange(1,10)
          numTwo = random.randrange(1,10)
          self.Answer = int(numOne) + int(numTwo) #change this
          self.strQuestion = "{} + {}".format(str(numOne), str(numTwo)) #and change this

    def answer(self):
          #answer checker

class leveltwo(tk.Frame):
     def __init__(self, parent, controller):
          tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

     #question def here

root = BattleMaths()
root.title("Battle Maths")
root.geometry("400x250")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you clearly explain, which is the variable that you want to use in multiple scopes?

Comment: I recommend you start by reading all of the answers linked to in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/7432

Answer (score 0):

Create the variables you want in the main class (BattleMaths), then you can alter them in the child classes via controller.my_variable.

Example: `self.Answer` created in `BattleMaths` and accessed in `levelone` via `controller.Answer`